# How is it possible to have discrete-mixed continuous Lyapunov function in this paper?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, lyapunov-functions

I'm reading [a very informative paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8794351?casa_token=ae6n4UMp3PMAAAAA:6CMvOBfrGuthgxyppnXDcqn-pRGp7yP2FnT7jw9ItbfSfvkb_Yy6qjunmnZr1VNXhme_0b7QGA). But I met some formulations hard to accept.

In the stability proof section (Sec. V, Theorem 5.2), they define a Lyapunov function as $V(s) = \frac{1}{2}m\|s\|^2$ and obtain the derivative using the relation $m\dot{s}=\epsilon(\zeta,u-K_v s)$.

However, the following formulation seems hard to accept since they suddenly have discrete terms as:

$\dot{V}=s^\top(-K_v s + \hat{f}_a(\zeta_k,u_k)-\hat{f}_a(\zeta_k,u_{k-1})+\epsilon(\zeta_k,u_k))\cdots(A)$.

If I understand the context correctly, the derivative should look like,

$\dot{V}=s^\top(-K_v s + f_a(\zeta,u)-\hat{f}_a(\zeta,u))\cdots(B)$.

How is it possible to bridge the gap between (A) and (B)? How can one have discrete terms in a continuous Lyapunov function without any notation?

*FYI, I asked them this question directly 2 month ago (plus the reminder 2 weeks ago) and I do not have the reply yet.

Comment: Without much context, yes it is possible, for instance in the context of sampled-data systems.

Comment: @KBS Thank you. I see, it's common...but even though I accept it's ok to have discrete terms, I could not find any relationship to fill the gap between (A) and (B) in the paper